# How to bring the navigationBar to the front

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, uinavigationbar

I've implemented a customised back button in swift 4 but the button doesn't show. I can see it in the layer that it's there but it's on the back and can't bring it to the front. 
Here is my code in viewDidload:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    collectionView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom: 58, right: 0)
    collectionView?.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 50, right: 0)
    collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "chat-bg")!)
    collectionView?.register(ChatMessageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

    collectionView?.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive


    let username = Auth.auth().currentUser?.displayName
    let backbutton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    backbutton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    backbutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "back"), for: .normal) // Image can be downloaded from here below link
    backbutton.setTitle(username, for: .normal)
    backbutton.setTitleColor(backbutton.tintColor, for: .normal) // You can change the TitleColor
    backbutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backAction), for: .touchUpInside)

    self.navigationController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backbutton)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(backbutton)
    setupInputComponents()
    setupKeyboardObservers()
}
```

Also, attached an screenshot of the layout
What I'm missing? any help appreciated.[image]

Comment: Show constraints assigned to collectionView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it. The issue wasn't related to this part of my code. It was related to another controller which was a CustomTabController and contains the navigationBar. I wasn't able to override that by this code. So, I moved the navigationBar section outside of the CustomBarController and that fixed the issue. This answer is very specific to my project and just shared it to let readers know that it's fixed in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.bringSubviewToFront(self.navigationController?.navigationBar)
```

OR

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.zPosition = 1


self.navigationController?.navigationBar.alpha = 1.0
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false
```

Comment: Edited my answer. check now

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check you **top constraint for collection** view it needs to be from **super view or safe area** not from the top of the main view. basically, the collection view hides your navigation bar. If you can tell me collection view constraint it will help to solve your issue easily.

Comment: I don't have any other constraints that what I mentioned above for this collectionViewController.

Comment: let yourBackImage = UIImage(named: "back_button_image")
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = yourBackImage
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = yourBackImage
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backItem?.title = "Custom"

Can you please try this code?

Comment: could it be because I used present instead of pushViewController? I changed that and now seeing back button on all viewControllers :D

Comment: Yes, right. If you want to present controller than you need to add view controller in uinavigation controller than present navigation controller but it will not show back button for display button you need to set navigation bar left bar button item. else just change animation using calayeranimation and push controller in the present style.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the exact same issue, in my case I fixed it by moving the following code to `viewWillAppear`

```
self.navigationController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backbutton)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(backbutton)
```

and then adding the following code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   super.viewDidAppear(animated)
   if let navigationController = navigationController {
       navigationController.view.bringSubviewToFront(navigationController.navigationBar)
    }
}
```